# Call by value with values interpreted as zero-argument functions vs call by name

Tags: scala

In this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337338/call-by-name-vs-call-by-value-in-scala-clarification-needed#comment18199691_13337382), @Ben suggested that call by name is equivalent to call by value where values are zero-argument functions. If I understood correctly,

```
def callByName(x: => Int) = {
  // some code
}
callByName(something())
```

is equivalent to

```
def callByValue(x: () => Int) = {
  // same code as above, but all occurrences of x replaced with x()
}
callByValue(()=>something())
```

(Edit: I fixed mistake in signature as pointed out by @MichaelZajac, @LukaJacobowitz: originally, it said `callByValue(x: Int)`.)

In other words, the whole "call by name" concept is just syntactic sugar: everything it does can be achieved (with a few extra keystrokes) using "call by value". If true, it makes it very easy to understand call by name; in fact, I've used this technique in python (python has first-class functions).

However, further down in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337338/call-by-name-vs-call-by-value-in-scala-clarification-needed#comment28060368_13337382), the discussion became somewhat more confusing, and I was left with the feeling that it's not quite so simple.

So is there something more substantive to "call by name"? Or is it just an automatic creation of zero-argument functions by the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant your `callByValue` function to take a `() => Int` instead of just an `Int` as otherwise it wouldn't make a lot of sense.

It's pretty much exactly what you think. The compiler generates a `Function0` instance. You can see this pretty nicely when you decompile Scala code with `Javap`.

Another thing of note is, that the generated `Function0` will be reevaluated every time you use the by-name parameter inside your function, so if you only want it to be computed once you'll want to do something like this:

```
def callByName(x: => Int) = {
   val a = x
   // do something with a here
}
```

[Here](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/26/call-by-name.html) is some more information on the whole concept.
Also you can see how Scala compiles by-name parameters quite neatly in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245454/scala-by-name-parameter-with-default-null-throws-nullpointerexception):

```
def getX[T <: X](constr: ⇒ T): Unit = {
    constr
}
```

decompiled in Java is equivalent to:

```
public <T extends X> void getX(Function0<T> constr) {
    constr.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but your example isn't quite right. The signature of `callByValue`, as written in your question, will evaluate `x` before `callByValue` is invoked.

The following would be roughly equivalent to a call-by-name:

```
def callByValue(x: () => Int) = {
  // same code as above, but all occurrences of x replaced with x()
}
```

The distinction is important, because your version of `callByValue` would only accept `Int`s, not functions that return `Int`s. It also wouldn't compile if you followed the procedure of replacing `x` with `x()`.

But yes, a call-by-name parameter of `=> A` is roughly equivalent to `() => A`, except that the former is simply more convenient to use. I say *roughly* because they *are* different types, and their applications are slightly different. You can specify `() => A` to be the type of something, but not `=> A`. And of course with `x: () => A`, you must manually call `x()` instead of `x`.